# Azure database initialization

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-sql-database

I have my API hosted on Azure and in api's WebConfig I have connection string to azure database

```
 <add name="FilmNetConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=filmnet.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=filmnetDb;User ID=sa;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have defined my database initializer and I want to initialize my azure database. I have tried to initialize that way however it is not working my azure database is still empty

```
    public class FilmNetContext : DbContext
    {
         public FilmNetContext() :
            base("FilmNetConnectionString")
         {
            Database.SetInitializer<FilmNetContext>(new FilmNetDbInitializer());
            Database.Initialize(true);
         }
```

how can I seed my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the initialiser to the Application_Start  method in your global.asax file.  That should do the trick.